# SQL string operation to get a substring

Tags: sql

how to get the last part after \ in the following string with SQL?

The column contains this:

AAA\BBB\CCC..\XXX

I want to get XXX with SQL in a typical select clause.

Answer (score 0):

sql supports something called a substring already built in.

```
select SUSBSTR(Column_name,StartingPoint, Number of Characters required) FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION
```

Not sure about it for mysql or others, but the above is for ORACLE and I wouldn't imagine it varies much.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT Susbstr(column_name, 
    Reverse(Substring(Reverse(columnname), 0, 
                                           Charindex('\', Reverse(columnname)))) 
       ) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  condition
```

Answer (score 0):

use Substring, since you're not telling your Database

this is query in MySQL (i am not sure with other DB will same or not)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '\', -1) FROM yourTable
```